# how to change labels background as same picture

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I started to learn Python one month ago. Sorry if my question is not good, this is my first question here.

I have made a small game using `tkinter`, but I have a problem.

I made a big label with a picture on it as background. Whenever I make more labels with text on them, the text will have gray background. However what I want is for every text to have the picture that I already placed as background.

Here's some code to explain it:

```
from tkinter import*
x=Tk()
x.geometry("1000x1000")
z=PhotoImage(file="D:\\Blue.gif")
v=Label(x,text="hi",font=100,fg="red",compound=CENTER,image=z,width=1000,height=1000)
v.place(x=0,y=0)
v1=Label(x,text="OO",font=100,fg="red")
v1.place(x=300,y=400) 
x.mainloop()
```

The `v` label works very well as long as I use compound with it. It shows the picture with the text "hi" on it.
However I want the `v1` label to have the same background as `v`, instead of gray background.

Comment: all widgets have background. You can use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) to put image and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All widgets have background - they can't be transparent.

You can use `tk.Canvas` to put text without background on image or transparent image on text.

effbot.org: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
c.pack()

# only GIF and PGM/PPM
#photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='test.gif')

# other formats
image = Image.open('test_transparent.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
# use in functions - solution for "garbage collector" problem
c.image = photo

i = c.create_image((WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2), image=photo)
t = c.create_text((WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2), text='Hello World')

root.mainloop()
```

Change order and you get image on text

```
t = c.create_text((WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2), text='Hello World')
i = c.create_image((WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2), image=photo)
```

**test_transparent.png** (image with transparent background)

[image]